# Visual studio Exchange Management Shell Add-ContentFilterPhrase cmdlet using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exchange-server, spam-prevention

I am a beginner in C# and needs help, I am attempting to write a code voor exchange anti spam, the help would be appreciated.

I have managed to set a domain using `Set-ContentFilterConfig` that works well:

```
//add  domain to sender filter button
private void btnDAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string param = cbDomain.SelectedItem.ToString();

        string filterConfig = "Set-SenderFilterConfig";            
        string ext = "add";

        txtOutput.Text = "Domain " + txtDInput.Text + " added to " + txtGServer.Text;
        string InputStr = txtDInput.Text;
        SpamFilterConfig(filterConfig, param, ext, InputStr);
}

// run command on exchange server
public void SpamFilterConfig(string filterConfig, string param, string ext, string InputStr)
{
        //credentials
        string xserver = $"http://" + txtGServer.Text + "/PowerShell";
        string loginName = txtGUsername.Text;
        string loginPassword = txtGPass.Text;

        SecureString ssLoginPassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char x in loginPassword)
        {
            ssLoginPassword.AppendChar(x);
        }

        ssLoginPassword.MakeReadOnly();

        PSCredential remoteMachineCredentials = new PSCredential(loginName, ssLoginPassword);

        // Set the connection Info
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(xserver), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", remoteMachineCredentials);

        Runspace runspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);

        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;

        //Set-SenderFilterConfig –BlockedDomains @{add=”domain.com”} ”
        // commands to execute
        Command SetSpamFilterConfig;
        Pipeline commandPipeLine;

        try
        {
            runspace.Open();
            SetSpamFilterConfig = new Command(filterConfig);
            SetSpamFilterConfig.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("–" + param, new Hashtable { { "" + ext + "", InputStr } }));
            commandPipeLine = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            commandPipeLine.Commands.Add(SetSpamFilterConfig);
            Collection<PSObject> getFilterConfigs = commandPipeLine.Invoke();

            if (getFilterConfigs.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (PSObject getFilterConfig in getFilterConfigs)
                {

                }
            }              

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            txtOutput.Text = "something went wrong";
        }
}
```

When i try to do the same for `add-contentfilterphrase` using below code it doesn't work. The code is basically the same only here the code is executed but the phrase is not added in exchange. Thank you in advance

```
private void btnCAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add-ContentFilterPhrase -Influence GoodWord -Phrase "text"            
        string filterConfig = "Add-ContentFilterPhrase";
        string param = $"Influence " + cbCContent.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string ext = "Phrase";

        txtCOutput.Text = "Word " + txtPhrase.Text + " added to " + txtGServer.Text;
        string InputStr = txtPhrase.Text;
        ContentFilterConfig(filterConfig, param, ext, InputStr);
    }


// run command on exchange server
    public void ContentFilterConfig(string filterConfig, string param, string ext, string InputStr)
    {
        //credentials
        string xserver = $"http://" + txtGServer.Text + "/PowerShell";
        string loginName = txtGUsername.Text;
        string loginPassword = txtGPass.Text;

        SecureString ssLoginPassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char x in loginPassword)
        {
            ssLoginPassword.AppendChar(x);
        }

        ssLoginPassword.MakeReadOnly();

        PSCredential remoteMachineCredentials = new PSCredential(loginName, ssLoginPassword);

        // Set the connection Info
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(xserver), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", remoteMachineCredentials);

        Runspace runspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);

        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;

        //Set-SenderFilterConfig –BlockedDomains @{add=”domain.com”} ”
        // commands to execute
        Command SetContentFilterConfig;
        Pipeline commandPipeLine;

        //string FinalTxt = $"\u0040{{" + ext + "=\u02DD" + InputStr + "\u02DD}";

        try
        {
            runspace.Open();
            SetContentFilterConfig = new Command(filterConfig);
            //SetContentFilterConfig.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("–" + param, new Hashtable { { "" + ext + "", InputStr } }));
            SetContentFilterConfig.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter(param, new Hashtable { { "" + ext + "", InputStr } }));
            commandPipeLine = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            commandPipeLine.Commands.Add(SetContentFilterConfig);
            Collection<PSObject> getFilterConfigs = commandPipeLine.Invoke();

            if (getFilterConfigs.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (PSObject getFilterConfig in getFilterConfigs)
                {

                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            txtOutput.Text = "something is wrong";
        }
    }
```

How can i use Add-contentFilterPhrase to set the parameter. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
    SetContentFilterConfig.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter(param, new Hashtable { { "" + ext + "", InputStr } }));
```

Comment: Please anybody?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the question I found the solution, after changing the button click event to:

```
private void btnCAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        string filterConfig = "Add-ContentFilterPhrase";
        string param = $"-Influence";
        string wordchoice = cbCContent.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string ext = $"-Phrase";
        string InputStr = txtPhrase.Text;


        txtCOutput.Text = "Word " + txtPhrase.Text + " added to " + txtGServer.Text;

        ContentFilterConfig(filterConfig, param, wordchoice, ext, InputStr);
    }
```

I have changed:

```
SetContentFilterConfig.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter(param, new Hashtable { { "" + ext + "", InputStr } }));
```

to:

```
SetContentFilterConfig.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter(param, wordchoice)); SetContentFilterConfig.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter(ext, InputStr));
```